# Search for element in json object to update/add some data in this object

Tags: javascript, json

I need to search for an element in a json object like this:

```
var new_a = 'new';
var json = { cells: 
    [ { type: 'model',
        id: '5aef826a1809',
        attrs: {
                text: 'first',
                a: 'changethis'
            }
      },
      { type: 'model',
        id: '2c11b8bd8112',
        attrs: {
                text: 'second'
            }
      }
    ]
}
```

1. Now I want to find the object with the `id = 5aef826a1809`, because I want to change the value of `a` to `new_a` or insert an `a`-element if it doesn't exist.
2. If `id = 2c11b8bd8112` a new `a`-element with the content `new_a` should be added.

I tried to use

```
var res = _.find(json.cells, { id: '5aef826a1809' }); // doesn't work
res.attrs.a = new_a; // this would update or add new field, right?
```

But this doesn't work

Comment: you want to change value of `a` or name of `a ` to `new_a` ?

Comment: I want to change the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
var new_a = 'new';
var json = {
    cells: [{
        type: 'model',
        id: '5aef826a1809',
        attrs: {
            text: 'first',
            a: 'changethis'
        }
    }, {
        type: 'model',
        id: '2c11b8bd8112',
        attrs: {
            text: 'second'
        }
    }]
};
var obj = json.cells.find(function (x) {
    return x.id == '5aef826a1809'
});
if (obj) { // return value if found else return undefined if not found
    obj.attrs.a = new_a;
    console.log(json);
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/83gy52ou/)

Answer (score 0):

Using this simple **for loop** should work, if that's what you're looking for:

```
for(var i = 0; i<json.cells.length; i++){
    if(json.cells[i].id == "5aef826a1809" || json.cells[i].id == "2c11b8bd8112"){
            json.cells[i].attrs.a = "new_a";
    }
}
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for searching, changing and for making a short circuit to prevent more iteration than necessary.

```js
var new_a = 'new',
    json = {
        cells: [{
            type: 'model',
            id: '5aef826a1809',
            attrs: {
                text: 'first',
                a: 'changethis'
            }
        }, {
            type: 'model',
            id: '2c11b8bd8112',
            attrs: {
                text: 'second'
            }
        }]
    };

function change(id) {
    json.cells.some(function (a) {
        var i = id.indexOf(a.id);
        if (~i) {
            a.attrs = a.attrs || {};
            a.attrs.a = new_a;
            id.splice(i, 1);
            if (!id.length) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}

change(['5aef826a1809', '2c11b8bd8112']);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(json, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```